# Using Trigger to insert record in another table, AND write back the ID into original record ..?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a simple trigger setup, which is used to insert records into a `RentJournal` table, whenever there is a record inserted in the `UnitAGA` table.

The `RentJournal` table has a primary key ID column named `RentJournalID`, which is auto incrementing. The `UnitAGA` table also has a nullable foreign key column named `RentJournalID`, which links each `UnitAGA` entry, to its corresponding entry in `RentJournal` table (which is inserted through the Trigger below).

Problem is that currently this Trigger is only inserting values into `RentJournal` table. But now I want to also fetch the ID assigned for each `RentJournal` entry through this Trigger, and write that into the corresponding `UnitAGA` record, whose insert actually triggered the Trigger in the first place. How do I do this ?

The Trigger code as of right now is this:

```
USE [RentDB]
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [RTS].[InsertRentJournalEntry]
   ON  [RTS].[UnitAGA]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO RTS.RentJournal
    (UnitId, AdjustmentType, EffectiveDate, ReferenceFormNo)
    SELECT
    UnitId, 'AGA', EffectiveDate, ReferenceFormNo FROM inserted
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `INSERT` logical table that is available in insert triggers:

> DML triggers use the deleted and inserted logical (conceptual) tables. They are structurally similar to the table on which the trigger is defined, that is, the table on which the user action is tried. The deleted and inserted tables hold the old values or new values of the rows that may be changed by the user action. For example, to retrieve all values in the deleted table, use: SELECT * FROM deleted
>    http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Then use `@@IDENTITY` to get the value of the identity column on your `RentJournal` table.

So you should be able to do something like:

```
update INSERTED set RentJournalID = @@IDENTITY
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot you can't update the logical tables. Still this should work: `update RTS.UnitAga set RentJournalId = @@IDENTITY where UnitId = (select UnitUd from inserted)`

Comment: @@IDENTITY is notorious for race condition problems because it returns the last value REGARDLESS of scope.  In other words, you are not guaranteed to return the value inserted within the trigger's transaction context.  You would have to use SCOPE_IDENTITY instead.

Comment: Also, I'm not able to test right now (which is why I'm posting as a comment and not an answer), but I'm fairly certain that this will result in a deadlock.  The inserted row will be locked due to the original insert.  Attempting to update the locked record will result in an unresolvable lock chain and fail, thus rolling everything back.

Comment: Thanks for the tips on `@@IDENTITY`. I have tested this and there isn't a deadlock.